# DLL as `src` of `<script>`

Tags: javascript, html, dll, scripting, client-side

I was browsing the source code of some website, and noticed a dll file being used as the `src` of a `<script>`.

(`view-source:http://www.yellowbridge.com/onlinelit/baijiaxing.php`)

It was something like: `<script src="some-dll-file.dll"></script>`

Several questions:

- I didn't know a `<script>` could be anything besides js.  What else can it be used for?
- Can you point me in the direction of some more information on this topic?  I've tried ggoogling around, but realized that I don't know what I should be googling exactly.
- Is this cross-platform?  I mean if I were to try this on epiphany on an ubuntu box, would it function and serve its purpose?
  I'm on a windows box right now and won't have access to anything else for a while, so I can't test it myself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Only JavaScript can be used as the client-side scripting language (and VBScript too, in IE). The `src` attribute just specifies some URL, and that URL will return the JavaScript.

So, the URL http://www.yellowbridge.com/lib/yellowbridge.dll actually does return  JavaScript. If you save its contents as a local text file, you can read the script.

Without knowing anything about the site or its JavaScript, I would guess they are dynamically generating some part of the script file from the DLL.

Edit: actually, looking at generated JS, I guess it's dynamically compressing the script on its way to the client.

Comment: I wonder if the Javascript code is static (I guess, as there are no parameters), and if so, why they bother to dynamically generate it; or, at least: appear to do so.

Comment: Judging by the appearance of the script, it looks like it's been compressed or minified. Perhaps the server performs on-demand script minification.

Answer (score 6):

Actually the file you are referring to '***yellowbridge.dll***' is a javascript file itself. You can view the source of this file.

It might be the dll that generates javascript code.

Answer (score 2):

If you think of what src-attribute stands for (source) it might be easier to understand. Just like the src-attribute of the img-element you should be able to include the source-code directly in the attribute. Wikipedia got a pretty good article about [data URI scheme](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme) where you could get started learning more.

In the case of the site you are linking to I guess the DLL generates JavaScript and sends it to the UA.

EDIT: This do not work in older versions of IE though. I know IE8 is said to support it. I am however not sure about IE7.